# Render video till video duration with filters

Tags: ffmpeg

In the below example, I need to render video with video time duration(i.e mp4)But this causes video execution to an infinite loop.

```
ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -stream_loop -1  -i w.webm   -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -filter_complex overlay  -y output.mp4
```

It should also work with vice versa

```
 ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1  -i w.webm   -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i v.mp4 -filter_complex overlay  -y output.mp4
```

For the above command, the output video should be rendered till  mp4 time duration.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overlay=shortest=1`

See the [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.

Comment: Oh Thank you. What if we have multiple overlay option like if we need to overlay multiple inputs where we need to keep shortest=1.

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Yes, the other overlays will also need shortest=1 if the additional inputs also use -stream_loop -1.